# How to solve this " E/SQLiteLog(1259): (1) near "GROUP": syntax error " in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, web-sql

This is my code

```
phoneNumber_g ="+91xxxxxxxx"
 db = window.openDatabase("groupDB", "1.0", "Group_Detail", 500000);
            db.transaction(function(tx){
                    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GROUP');
                    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GROUP (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,phoneno TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT " ")',[],function(tx,res){    
                        alert("sucess");
                    },function(err){
            alert("error occured while creation");
                                });
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO GROUP (name,phoneno) VALUES ("Anand",'+phoneNumber_g+')');
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM GROUP',[],function(tx,res){
                                       var leng = res.rows.length;
                                       var len = "";
                                       console.log("DEMO table: " + leng + " rows found.");
                                       for (var i=0; i<leng; i++){
                                           len = res.rows.item(i).id;
                                           alert(res.rows.item(i).phoneno);
                                       }

                                    },function(err){
                                        alert("error occured : "+err.message);
                                    });
                            }, dbError, successDb);
```

I want to save the details into the db dynamically. But the error repeats again and again, please help me to fix this one

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong structure of phonegap. Please see phonegap document section "Storage".

first create and insert script.

second in successDb function again

db = window.openDatabase("groupDB", "1.0", "Group_Detail", 500000);

db.transaction ...

in that you can get select query.

and please see sqlite datatypes too. VARCHAR(25) is not needed.

See this link for example.

[Click here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#SQLResultSet)